# Azure Pipeline Task for Kustomize File Generation Fails on Azure

Tags: azure, kubernetes, kustomize

I have developed an Azure Pipeline task to generate a Kustomize file, which functions correctly on my laptop but not on Azure. It used to work before, but something has changed in Azure that has caused it to stop functioning. Can anyone provide guidance on how to resolve this issue or identify the changes in Azure that may have caused it to fail? Thank you

```
- task: KubernetesManifest@0
  displayName: Generate kustomize
  name:  Generate kustomize
  inputs:
      action: 'bake'
      renderType: 'kustomize'
      kustomizationPath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'


##[error]error: invalid Kustomization: json: cannot unmarshal string into Go struct field Kustomization.patches of type types.Patch
```

Azure consistently raises an error whenever there are patches present. By removing patches from the Kustomize file, I was able to resolve the issue. I don't know what wrong with Kustomization.patches

```
# kustomize patched file
resources:
  - ../base
namespace: prod
patches:
  - patch.yaml
```

Answer (score 0):

I have got same error due to non compatible yaml format (old), check if you  are using same **kustomize** versions in your laptop and Azure.

Couple solutions that worked for me:

Add *path* prior to file in *patches*

```
# kustomize patched file 
resources:
  - ../base
namespace: prod
patches:
  - path: patch.yaml
```

Replace *patches* with *patchesStrategicMerge* (deprecated but seems to work)

```
# kustomize patched file 
resources:
  - ../base
namespace: prod
patchesStrategicMerge:
  - patch.yaml
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've identified the issue. To resolve it, I updated Kubernetes to a more recent version in order to support the execution of kustomize files. It's worth noting that I'm still using the older deployment files and haven't transitioned to any new formats, which seems a bit unusual.